# In Islam, does masturbation break chastity?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, masturbation

"And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors." - Quran (Chapter 23 Verses 5-7)

When scholars are asked whether masturbation is haram or not, they usually refer to these verses. So basically, this means masturbation counts as using your private parts to perform illegal sexual acts. Does this mean masturbation breaks chastity?

Comment: The ayah is referring to actual sex and not masturbation.  There are scholars who say masturbation isn't haraam.  Masturbation doesn't break chastity because you're not having sex.  Otherwise masturbation would be Zina and you would be lashed.

Comment: @Sayyid does this ayat also apply to oral sex and anal sex?

Comment: This Question is directly related to your other Question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/what-is-islams-perception-of-chastity and a simple answer is: those scholars who consider any other "use" of the private parts as illegal will consider masturbation and oral-sex as haram and therefore one could conclude that this would break chastity, at least according to this opinion. Some scholars don't consider masturbation haram (in cases). Some allow oral-sex at least without ejaculation... so you see we can get a lots of answers!