# Can a Muslim man who has engaged in pre-marital sex marry a virgin woman?

Tags: fiqh, sex, zina

Is it possible for a guy who has had premarital sex, be married to a virgin girl?

To what extent does the Quran and the Sunnah say that a non-virgin only deserves a non-virgin?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more how this site works and about our model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour9 and visit our [help]. The Quran doesn't say "non-virgin", but "chaste" meaning a person who has never had a haram relationship or (if yes) repented from it sincerly.

Comment: You answer can be found in http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/i-had-premarital-sex-with-my-cousin-now-i-have-questions-about-marriage and you and an explanation of chatitiy according Islam is here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/what-is-islams-perception-of-chastity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can marry a virgin woman after he repents. The prohibition applies to those who fornicated and didn't repent. Ibn Kathir (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal (may Allah have mercy on him) was of the view
>   that the marriage of a chaste man to an unchaste woman is not valid so
>   long as she remains like that, unless she is asked to repent.
>
> If she repents, the marriage contract will be valid, otherwise it will
>   not. Similarly, it is not valid for a free, chaste woman to be given
>   in marriage to a man who is immoral and unchaste, **unless he repents
>   sincerely**, because Allah, may He be exalted, says (interpretation of
>   the meaning): “Such a thing is forbidden to the believers” [an-Noor
>   24:3]." -- [Source](https://islamqa.info/en/199600)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read and re-read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and the comment of Tom Au  on http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/were-the-english-behind-the-creation-of-belgium  "At SE, "duplicate" means that the answers are duplicate, not the questions...." to understand the SE definition of duplicate posts!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for the clarification. I answered it because I thought it wouldn't look good if a well researched question like this had no proper answer.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin well you'll find a lot of answers of mine of that kind the point is i witnessed that issue in history se and learnt from it, as OP is actually sitting in front of me ;)

Comment: @Sassir If a question shows research effort, even if it's a duplicate question, it's still a good question. I don't find anything objectionable in answering such question.

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.